# creating a rolling menu: rolling just once

Tags: javascript, arrays, css-transitions, transition

[EDIT]

I rebuild my code after [numbtongue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3254405/numbtongue) hint. It looks totally different now, and is working pretty well. Except that it is working once only ! After one roll, it doesn't roll anymore...
I have two functions : one for transitions and the other one for replacing content. In the 'transition' function, I chose to add classes to the element to transit, and add some CSS for these classes. 
When I run my code, it seems that everything goes perfectly all the time, except that the transitions don't happen. What's wrong ??

JSFIDDLE : jsfiddle.net/arnaudambro/ode8bowb/2/

[ORIGINAL]

I am trying to create a "rolling menu", looking quite like the one from [this awwwarded](https://www.awwwards.com/sites/north-east-venture) website : [north-east-venture.com](http://north-east-venture.com/) on the right side of the page (no advertising from me at all, just for you to know what I am refering too, for a better understanding of the issue I am confronted with).

What I am looking for is: when someone click on one item of the menu, this item goes directly up, and the items which were above would go under the stack.
I made something up which is quite working here :

JS Fiddle : jsfiddle.net/arnaudambro/7s6ncxyp/

But as you can see, there are no transitions.

Here is the code showing the "working" transition :

JSFiddle : jsfiddle.net/arnaudambro/xtrvsgor/

To make the transitions working, I had to comment the lines 84, 153, 172 and 174 in the JS.

I tried everything I could to make the transitions working in the whole menu, but it seems that when I "populate the new menu", every transition is killed.

What i wrong with my code ?

Comment: I am not sure you can use apostrophe like this const item = `.. Do you have a complete running demo of your menu on your site or fiddle, otherwise can't find all included files..

Comment: Why couldn't I use the backtick ? I updated my post with a fiddle instead of the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success ! 
With some timeouts, I did the trick. Unfortunately, it is working but still a bit jerky, because it seems there is no other choice with timeouts. I tried to measure time spent to repopulateMenu to do its job, and put it as a setTimeout value, but it didn't work, the time was too short.
Anyway, it's quite working already, nice !

```js
/*------------------------------ Variables -----------------------------------*/

const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];
const itemsLink = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item-link')];
const itemsContent = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item-content')];

let translateYHeight = itemsLink[0].offsetHeight;
console.log(translateYHeight)
let textContentItemAtTheTopOfTheStack;
let transitionInSeconds;
let transitionInMilliSeconds;
let clickedItemIndex;

/*--------------------------- Functions - callbacks --------------------------*/

//Get the index. Called in the STEP 1.

function getTheIndexOfTheClickedItem(e) {
  //Variable
  let clicked;

  //We select the <p> only
  if (e.target.tagName == "LI") {
    clicked = e.target.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
  } else if (e.target.tagName == "A") {
    clicked = e.target.firstElementChild;
  } else if (e.target.tagName == "P") {
    clicked = e.target;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  //Nothing happen if we clicked on the first item
  if (clickedItemIndex === 0) {
    return;
  }

  //We get the index of the clicked item
  clickedItemIndex = items.indexOf(clicked.parentElement.parentElement);

  //We get the textContent of the clicked item, so that when the textContent
  //of the first item in the menu is the proper textContent, we are done
  textContentItemAtTheTopOfTheStack = itemsContent[clickedItemIndex].textContent;

  //We set the total transition time to 1 second
  transitionInSeconds = 1 / clickedItemIndex;
  transitionInMilliSeconds = transitionInSeconds * 1000;

  translateAndFade();
}

/*--------------------------- STEP 1 --------------------------*/

function translateAndFade() {

  //We put the proper transition depending on when the translateAndFade function
  //is called
  let transitionStyle;

  if (clickedItemIndex === 1) {
    transitionStyle = 'ease-in-out';
  } else if (itemsLink[1].textContent.trim() === textContentItemAtTheTopOfTheStack) {
    transitionStyle = 'ease-out';
  } else if (itemsLink[clickedItemIndex].textContent.trim() === textContentItemAtTheTopOfTheStack) {
    transitionStyle = 'ease-in';
  } else {
    transitionStyle = 'linear';
  }

  //We add the transitions and fadings we want
  itemsLink.forEach(link => {
    if (itemsLink.indexOf(link) === 0) {
      //We add the fade-out for the first menu-item
      link.style.opacity = 0;
      link.style.transform = `translateY(-${translateYHeight}px)`;
      link.style.transition = `all ${transitionInSeconds}s ${transitionStyle}`;
    } else if (itemsLink.indexOf(link) === (itemsLink.length - 1)) {
      //We add the fade-in for the last menu-item
      link.firstElementChild.textContent = itemsLink[0].textContent.trim();
      link.style.opacity = 1;
      link.style.transform = `translateY(-${translateYHeight}px)`;
      link.style.transition = `all ${transitionInSeconds}s ${transitionStyle}`;
    } else {
      //We translate every menu-item one step up
      link.style.transform = `translateY(-${translateYHeight}px)`;
      link.style.transition = `all ${transitionInSeconds}s ${transitionStyle}`;
    }
  });

  //We call repopulateMenu, to repopulate the menu, with enough timeout to
  //let the transition happening
  window.setTimeout(repopulateMenu, transitionInMilliSeconds);
}

/*--------------------------- STEP 2 --------------------------*/


function repopulateMenu() {

  //We remove the transitions
  itemsLink.forEach(link => {
    if (itemsLink.indexOf(link) === 0) {
      //We remove the fade-out for the first menu-item
      link.style.opacity = 1;
      link.style.transform = ``;
      link.style.transition = ``;
    } else if (itemsLink.indexOf(link) === (itemsLink.length - 1)) {
      //We remove the fade-in for the last menu-item
      link.style.opacity = 0;
      link.style.transform = ``;
      link.style.transition = ``;
    } else {
      //We remove the translation of all of them
      link.style.transform = ``;
      link.style.transition = ``;
    }
  });

  //We update the textContents
  itemsContent.forEach(item => {
    // We put back emptiness for the last menu-item
    if (itemsContent.indexOf(item) === (itemsContent.length - 1)) {
      item.textContent = '';
    } else {
      //We replace the content of the item by the one below it
      item.textContent = itemsContent[itemsContent.indexOf(item) + 1].textContent.trim();
    }
  });

  //We do all again until the proper item-menu is on top of the stack.
  if (itemsContent[0].textContent != textContentItemAtTheTopOfTheStack) {
    window.setTimeout(translateAndFade, 20);
  } else {
    return;
  }
}



/*--------------------------- Event listeners --------------------------------*/
menu.addEventListener('click', getTheIndexOfTheClickedItem);
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: rgba(41, 44, 45, 1.00);
}

.menu {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
}

.transition-translateY {
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: translateY(-44px);
}

.transition-fadeIn {
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: translateY(-44px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.transition-fadeOut {
  transition: all 1s;
  transform: translateY(-44px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.item {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-align: left;
  /*border: 1px solid #000;*/
}

.item-link,
.item-link:hover {
  height: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="item-link">
        <p class="item-content" data-menu-position="0">Item 1</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="item-link">
        <p class="item-content" data-menu-position="1">Item 2</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="item-link">
        <p class="item-content" data-menu-position="2">Item 3</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="item-link">
        <p class="item-content" data-menu-position="3">Item 4</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="item-link">
        <p class="item-content" data-menu-position="4">Item 5</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <a href="#" class="item-link" style="opacity:0">
        <p class="item-content" data-menu-position="5"></p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>



</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint: clicking on links loses menu position (sets it to array size currently = 5), instead should be cycling trough (see attached) for other links..[image]

Comment: thanks for the hint ! even if I rebuild the code without your remark, it made a spark to me and I was able to go on and improve the code. Yet there is still an issue, I hope you'll see it !

Comment: it works if you click "quickly" second time before roll is completed.. I've noticed (similarly in inspector) that when roll completes classes are removed/restored to previous values which could be why..